# Angular 5: Why in debug mode it's no show up 'Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules'

Tags: angular, angular5, xdebug, production

When I run for debug mode with this command: `npm run build`, I will have all the dist folder and I can deploy the project.

When I run for production with this command: `npm run build -- --prod`, I will have this error 'Component is part of the declaration of 2 modules'.

My question is: Why this difference between the two mode ? Is this caused by the AOT option?

Comment: Probably, try running `npm run build -- --aot` and see if it pops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a thing about Angular's Ahead of Time compilation. Because it eliminates code, it is a lot stricter than the debug compile and several other errors are also only reported in AOT compiles.

Generally, I do a `ng build -prod` (which implies AOT) before I commit for exactly this reason.

Since you're using the `npm` scripts, I would use the syntax @trichetriche suggested:

```
npm run build -- --aot
```